# battery laptop always 0% cannot fully charged

Tags: windows-7, battery-life, battery

i have laptop Toshiba l645 and the battery cannot fully charged (always 0%).
How make it back to normal ?
In windows 7 i ever try safe mod and it is still 0%

Comment: Are you sure the battery is not dead? Have you tried removing the battery and inserting it back in?

Comment: dead or no i still don't understand. i ever removing it, but still 0%

Comment: Your battery is dead. Its EOL, it needs to be replaced. It cannot be used any longer. Buy a new one and put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the battery in this condition, the principle is to do the calibration, the battery and notebook in order to find the 'agreement' about the contents of the real capacity of the battery and the indicator is displayed.

Some laptop comes with a calibration menu in its BIOS. If it exists, can be tried several times to perform a calibration cycle. That is, after a calibration cycle is complete, use a laptop with a battery to run out. Then do the calibration again. Perform this process is between 3-5 x round. After that, see if the indicator is in conformity with the use of real / nearly.

Calibration process can also use third party programs, such as the Battery Eater. The calibration process is carried out about 2-5 rounds.
While the way the 'rough' is, by emptying the battery is completely discharged, then recharge the battery for 5 hours with a dead laptop condition. Then the battery until they really run out again. Perform this process is between 2-3 times. After that, you can try and see if the battery has a capacity corresponding real.

Comment: i ever try to charge my battery until fully charged (100%) and i remove the charger, suddenly about 1 minute my laptop is turn off (battery is empty)

Comment: how long you use the laptop (battery) it? usually the battery is worn out.

Comment: about 2 years since i bought laptop

Comment: ow same as mine. i also have toshiba laptop, my problem 1 year ago. than i bought new battery. because i brought to laptop service every one said that "you must buy new battery because preservation of the battery depends on how often he used".  and usually battery is worn out average 2 years since bought laptop

Comment: okay, so I bought a new battery